# How can i display fetched mysql data into HTML dropdown list in NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js

hey i am total new in node.js..

Can U any one please Explain me step by Step how i can display values into dropdownlist.. i have just create a single file.. File name is fetch.js
which get(fetch) all the values from mysql.. in the form of JSON.. here is my code..

```js
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'localhost',
  port  : 3306, //port mysql
  user : 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'node_js'
  
});

console.log('MySQL Connection details  '+connection);

http.createServer(function (request, response) 
{ 
        console.log('Creating the http server');
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM `emp` where Branch="PHP"', function(err, rows, fields)
        {
                console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
                response.end();
        }); 

}).listen(8084);
```

my database

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emp` (
  `ID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Branch` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

please help me in this 
Thanks in Adv.

Comment: This link may help: [Dynamic Dropdown in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218243/dynamic-dropdown-in-node-js)
Thanks