# Express dynamic dropdown menu

Tags: html, express, ejs

This question has been asked before but not fully resolved.

So I have one dropdown menu and depending on user's selection a second dropdown menu will populate with specific choices.

Javascript

```
  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
          title: 'Design your one line.',
          moduleType: moduleType,
          moduleManufacturer: moduleManufacturer,
          modTableTitle: modTableTitle,
      }
  );
});

var modTableTitle = "Module Specification";

var moduleManufacturer = [];
var newArray = [];
    for (var x in moduleType.specs) {
        newArray[x] = moduleType.specs[x].Manufacturer;
        if (newArray[x] != newArray[x-1]) {
            moduleManufacturer.push(newArray[x]);
        }
}
```

EJS

```
            </div>
            <select class="form-control" name="selectModuleManufacturer">
                <option selected disabled>Select Module Manufacturer</option>
                <% for (var x in moduleManufacturer) { %>
                <option><%= moduleManufacturer[x]; %></option>
                <% } %>
            </select>
        </div>
```

The second dropdown contains specs of the manufacturer selected and it's all part of a json object, so can someone help me write the second part? Appreciate it.

Comment: How about this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218243/dynamic-dropdown-in-node-js)?